# Implement update panel in sharepoint 2010 for postback effect by one the webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, updatepanel, web-parts

Background:
I have a site on sharepoint 2010 with 5 site pages, each page have some content.

Problem:
One of the page, have tab web part from MSDN, this webpart is used to implement tabs in SP site, here is the link of webpart.
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/zonetabs

Now, when i implement it, it posts back the page, on switching between tabs, that gives a bad impression(as the complete page reloads).
I only need to handle that postback effect. by using some update panel or something.

Can i do anything with master page ? or any other way out to solve this out.
Any suggestion will be appreciable.

Comment: What type of page are you using? Is it standard web part page or custom layouts page?

Comment: The source code is available, just wrap the whole thing in an update panel compile the webpart and redeploy.

Comment: Specifically, im simply using a site page, without any customization in pages layout or other.